# Restart existing Docker container with port forwarding

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I know that to start a new container in Docker, I have to run the following command:

`docker run -ti -p 3000:3000 <image name>`

But this will create a fresh new container. How can I perform port forwarding in an existing container which is stopped previously and can be seen by:

`docker ps -a`

I can start an existing container using:

`docker start -a -i <container name>`

Is there a way so that I can perform the port forwarding to my host PC from inside the container after I start it? My container image is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Original answer (Nov 2015, docker 1.9.1)

The ability to change runtime parameters (parameters set on docker run, like port mapping) was asked since July 2014 in [docker issue 3285](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3285), or even before that in dec 2013 in [issues 2045](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2045).

There is a [PR in progress for a `docker set` command](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15078).
So it is not yet available right now (docker 1.9.1)

---

Update February 2016 (docker 1.10.1)

[docker issue 3285](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3285) is now closed, since [PR 15078](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15078) has been merged, giving us the [`docker update` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/).
However, this is for updating container *resources* only (memory, cpu). *Not* port mapping yet. For that, you still have to follow [issue 2045](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2045).